# How do I set my new SSD card for the OS and leave my HDD for my files?

Tags: 20.04, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I bought new RAM and an SDD to improve my computer's performance. A friend of mine installed them. It didn't work as expected. I want the OS to boot and be in the new ssd and leave the hdd for all the files. Maybe /home could be there I don't know if that's possible. Right now I think my OS is still on the HDD and the SDD is partitioned but not really sure what's it's function. [SSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjIsW.png) and [HDD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znNOf.png) partitions.

Any idea how to config these two disks? Can it be done from Gparted? I read something about Clonezilla am I close? The files I want to save are safe on a pen drive and also on the hdd in the old home directory. I have a bootable pendrive with the Ubuntu ISO. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like the Ubuntu is installed in the SSD.

Comment: What does this show? `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid`

Comment: Ubuntu is on the 1TB `sda` device, but how can one tell from the information provided whether `sda` is the HDD or the SSD?

Comment: @oldfred this is what the terminal shows:
sda    931,5G                                   
├─sda1
│    vfat     850M  26,2M ESP   EFI system partition
│                                         /boot/efi  EECA-942D
├─sda2
│    vfat       5G        OS    Basic data partition
│                                                    1606-FC09
└─sda3
     ext4   925,7G        UBUNTU   3f028a6a-123d-45c2-bac9-7f28245c401c
sdb         223,6G                                   
└─sdb1
     ext4   223,6G  74,9G                 /          8e2ccf46-15a4-4f92-bffe-66d234109e40

Comment: You cannot post terminal output in comments, it should be in question, so formatting can be maintained. Not really readable in comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how I have things set up. You really need the OS on the SSD to benefit from it. If I were you I'd just start over. Disconnect the HDD. If the OS is on the HDD it won't boot. If it boots then the OS is already on the SSD.

If the OS has been installed on the HDD start afresh. Make an installation USB. Disconnect the HDD so that the SSD is the only drive in your system and then install the fresh OS onto it. After it's installed you can connect the HDD for other stuff. I think it's best to install applications you use on the SSD to benefit from the increased performance though.

Comment: Makes sense to me, only one question: if OP disconnects the HDD upon installation time, and connects its again afterwards, will Ubuntu automatically mount the EXT4 partition on the newly added HDD on each boot, or does OP need to set it up manually in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: You shouldnt have to touch fstab, it'll mount them at boot time, If you end up with an OS on both the SDD and the HDD you may have to select which disk to boot (the BIOS will have a boot options button usually F11 or F10) then format the HDD once your OS has loaded or you could format the HDD before you install onto the SDD. Backup anything you want to keep before you start

Comment: @Artillery that’s what my friend said too, makes sense. 
Last question, when you say that installed apps should be on the SSD, if I install my OS in there it will automatically set the usr/bin inside it, right? Thus /home could be in the HDD afterwards

Comment: Once you install your OS on the SSD your Home folder will be on the SSD too. Its just a folder tho. If you want to work from a folder on the HDD it will work no problem, but file accesses will be a lot slower than on the SSD :)

Comment: What I mean is you could make a folder on your HDD and call it anything you like and use that instead of the default Home folder. You could also create a symbolic link from the default Home folder on the SSD to the one you create on  the HDD.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot! I'll try everything and let you know how it goes! awesome support :) have a cool weekend!